# Anatomy of seeds (dicot and monocot)

Tags: botany, seeds

Do all dicot seeds have endosperm? Will they be retain as they grow and what are the difference with its monocot counterpart?

Comment: You are asking a broad question. Can you please add relevant details to narrow down your question so that it is answerable in a few paragraphs (at max).

Comment: Will dicots always have endosperm?

Comment: no all dicots seeds don't retain endosperm, e.g.: Fabaceae